# Google Calendar not displaying correct time

Tags: timezone, google-calendar-api

I have a Google Calendar for a school website I'm working on and am using the Google API to display the next five calendar events. One problem is that the time displays on a 24 hour clock instead of AM and PM, but that's not my main problem. The main problem is that while the events display the correct time on the website, when you click on the event to view it in the calendar event view, it will only display GMT time instead of Eastern Time. While logged into the Google account, the events display the right time zone, but whenever you view it while not logged in, it defaults to GMT.

I have tried changing it to another time zone and change it back, didn't fix it.

I also made sure all settings in both the calendar and the account were set to Eastern time zone, at least everywhere I could find it.

I've seen a lot of people with similar problems on Google sites using the ical or other feeds, but I haven't seen anyone with the problem using a code similar to mine.

The website is live: http://fletcheracademy.com.  And here is the main javascript code that pulls it.

There's probably some details I'm missing, let me know if there's anything else you need to know. Thanks so much!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 google.load("gdata", "2.x");

 function init() {
    google.gdata.client.init(handleGDError);
    loadDeveloperCalendar();
 }


 function loadDeveloperCalendar() {
    loadCalendarByAddress('fletcheracademycalendar@gmail.com');
 }

 function padNumber(num) {
    if (num <= 9) {
       return "0" + num;
    }
    return num;
 }

 function loadCalendarByAddress(calendarAddress) {
    var calendarUrl = 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/' +     
                       calendarAddress + '/public/full';

    loadCalendar(calendarUrl);
}


 function loadCalendar(calendarUrl) {
    var service = new 
        google.gdata.calendar.CalendarService('gdata-js-client-samples-simple');
    var query = new google.gdata.calendar.CalendarEventQuery(calendarUrl);
    query.setOrderBy('starttime');
    query.setSortOrder('ascending');
    query.setFutureEvents(true);
    query.setSingleEvents(true);
    query.setMaxResults(5);

    service.getEventsFeed(query, listEvents, handleGDError);
 }


 function handleGDError(e) {
    document.getElementById('jsSourceFinal').setAttribute('style', 'display:none');
    if (e instanceof Error) {
      alert('Error at line ' + e.lineNumber + ' in ' + e.fileName + '\n' + 'Message: ' + e.message);
      if (e.cause) {
         var status = e.cause.status;
         var statusText = e.cause.statusText;
         alert('Root cause: HTTP error ' + status + ' with status text of: ' + statusText);
        }
    } else {
        alert(e.toString());
    }
}

function listEvents(feedRoot) {
    var entries = feedRoot.feed.getEntries();
    var eventDiv = document.getElementById('events');
    if (eventDiv.childNodes.length > 0) {
        eventDiv.removeChild(eventDiv.childNodes[0]);
    }     
    var ul = document.createElement('ul');
    //document.getElementById('calendarTitle').innerHTML = 
    // "Calendar: " + feedRoot.feed.title.$t;

    var len = entries.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var entry = entries[i];
        var title = entry.getTitle().getText();
        var startDateTime = null;
        var startJSDate = null;
        var times = entry.getTimes();
        if (times.length > 0) {
            startDateTime = times[0].getStartTime();
            startJSDate = startDateTime.getDate();
        }
    var entryLinkHref = null;
    if (entry.getHtmlLink() != null) {
        entryLinkHref = entry.getHtmlLink().getHref();
    }
    var dateString = (startJSDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + startJSDate.getDate();
    if (!startDateTime.isDateOnly()) {
        dateString += " " + startJSDate.getHours() + ":" + 
        padNumber(startJSDate.getMinutes());
    }

    var li = document.createElement('li');

    if (entryLinkHref != null) {
        entryLink = document.createElement('a');
        entryLink.setAttribute('href', entryLinkHref);
        entryLink.appendChild(document.createTextNode(title));
        li.appendChild(entryLink);
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' - ' + dateString));
    } else {
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(title + ' - ' + dateString));
    }       

    ul.appendChild(li);
}
eventDiv.appendChild(ul);
}

google.setOnLoadCallback(init);

</script>
```

Comment: Please properly indent your code in the future.  Unindented code is hard to read when you don't know the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

Where you have:

```
var calendarUrl = 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/' + calendarAddress + '/public/full';
```

you should add something like:

&ctz=Europe/Lisbon

Check [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) for the correct name of your timezone.